# Why does mySQL statement throw a parse error for a comparison that works for a print or echo statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set a switch based on a comparison of the result from mySQL table query. The query works if I am using a print or echo, but throws a syntax error when trying to use the exact same loop for a comparison. Code for comparison that throws the error is below.

```
//Define query for database entry lookup
$sql = "SELECT * FROM email_auth WHERE useremail='$user_email_address'";

//Define result for database entry lookup
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

//Find match for email authentication
$email_count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  if ( $row['authID'] == $user_email_auth ) { $validemailrequest = "true" }  //Line 60
  $email_count++;
}
```

And the error I am getting...

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in
<b>/home/user/public_html/send_email.php</b> on line <b>60</b>
```

Yet works when using same for print...

```
//Define query for database entry lookup
$sql = "SELECT * FROM email_auth WHERE useremail='$user_email_address'";

//Define result for database entry lookup
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

//Find match for email authentication
$email_count = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  print $row['authID'];
  $email_count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a semi-colon missing after the conditional code.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if ( $row['authID'] == $user_email_auth ) { $validemailrequest = "true"; }  //Line 60
    $email_count++;
}
```

Comment: Arrrggh... always the little boogers that getcha! Thanks Joe (as I head for the coffee pot). You get the answer because I see you were first, but thanks to everyone else that provided a correct answer as well!

Comment: No problem! Doesn't matter how much code you write you always get caught out by the gotchas! As an extra tip - I know it seems like less code by putting the if condition and the conditional code on one line, but I **always** put the conditional code (even if its one line) on it's own line. It really does help to avoid things like this - your IDE should pick up the error if not the PHP error message `Error on line 6` will give you a more specific location for the error.

Answer (score 0):

This line is missing a semicolon `;`,

```
$validemailrequest = "true";
```

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon is missing after `$validemailrequest = "true"`